# Client-Server android chat app - NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking

I'm doing easy chat for android. 
I'm using [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W6XfjfEnrF0&t=1521s%22this%20tutorial%22) to do so. I have simple android client and java client.

I'm starting in few steps:

1. Start server || message server: "Waiting client to connect"
2. Start client || no message in server
3. Click button || message server: "Client connected" and "Message from client:
                  Connected" and "Server has ended."
4. Android client crash with NetworkOnMainThreadException

Message of step 3 will appear onCreate client, so when I start app. When I click button it should send message to server. It crash with this error:

```
01-10 10:31:26.892 27458-27458/com.example.rachel.testapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.example.rachel.testapp, PID: 27458
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429) 
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
  Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1303)
     at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
     at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:157)
     at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
     at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
     at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295)
     at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
     at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
     at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:254)
     at com.example.rachel.testapp.MainActivity.sendMessage(MainActivity.java:88)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429) 
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

I have android app like so

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private static final String hostname = "localhost";
    private static final int portnumber = 60125;
    private static final String debugString = "debug";
    private Socket socket = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    Log.i(debugString, "Attempting to connect to server");
                    socket = new Socket(hostname, portnumber);
                    Log.i(debugString, "Connection established");

                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
                    bw.write("Connected");
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.flush();

                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    System.out.println("Message from server:" + br.readLine());


                } catch (IOException e)

                {
                    Log.e(debugString, e.getMessage());
                    //e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();



    }

    public void sendMessage(View view)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Klik", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        BufferedWriter bw =null;

        try
        {
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));

            bw.write(editText.getText().toString());
            bw.newLine();
            bw.flush();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.e(debugString, e.getMessage());
        }




    }

}
```

And java server

```
public class main 
{

    private static final int portnumber = 60125;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Serwer port: "+ portnumber);
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portnumber);

            System.out.println("Waiting to connect");
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Client connected");

            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
            bw.write("Message from server");
            bw.newLine();
            bw.flush();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            String data;
            while((data = br.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println("Message from client:"+data);


            System.out.println("Server has ended.");
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();            
        }

    }




}
```

Comment: Have you even tried to google "NetworkOnMainThreadException"? This error is very common among Android-beginners so you should have found something putting minimal effort into this.

Comment: In Android you cannot execute Network Operations on the UI thread. You have to use `AsyncTask` to connect to the server. here is a nice example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example

Comment: Try asynctask instead of thread

Comment: See section [Introducing Network Operations on a Separate Thread](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#intro) of this android developer lesson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do network operation on main thread. Do it in the background task. better use `AsyncTask` or change to this

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try
                {
                    Log.i(debugString, "Attempting to connect to server");
                    socket = new Socket(hostname, portnumber);
                    Log.i(debugString, "Connection established");

                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
                    bw.write("Connected");
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.flush();

                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    System.out.println("Message from server:" + br.readLine());


                } catch (IOException e)

                {
                    Log.e(debugString, e.getMessage());
                    //e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
```